# sliding image continuosly with fade effect in div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want the image should be continuously rotating at an interval of time ,and when mouse is move over that image rotation should stop and when click on that it should zoom ,and when mouse leave it should again start rotating where it has stoped.

I have a div as

```
<div   id="simplegallery2" style="width: 1024px; height: 300px; display: block;"></div>
```

jquery code as

```
var mygallery2 = new simpleGallery({
                wrapperid: "simplegallery2",
                dimensions: [1024, 300],
                imagearray: [

                    ["Banner/img/3.jpg", ""],
                    ["Banner/img/4.jpg", "", "", ""],
                    ["Banner/img/5.jpg", "", "", ""],
                    //["Banner/img/4.jpg", "", "", ""],

                ],
                autoplay: [true, 2500, 100],
                persist: false,
                fadeduration: 2000,
                oninit: function () {
                },
                onslide: function (curslide, i) {

                }

            })
```

and jquery slider plugin as

```
function simpleGallery(settingarg) {


    this.setting=settingarg
    settingarg=null
    var setting=this.setting
    setting.panelheight=(parseInt(setting.navpanelheight)>5)? parseInt(setting.navpanelheight) : parseInt(simpleGallery_navpanel.panel.height)
    setting.fadeduration=parseInt(setting.fadeduration)
    setting.curimage=(setting.persist)? simpleGallery.routines.getCookie("gallery-"+setting.wrapperid) : 0
    setting.curimage=setting.curimage || 0 //account for curimage being null if cookie is empty
    setting.preloadfirst=(!jQuery.Deferred)? false : (typeof setting.preloadfirst!="undefined")? setting.preloadfirst : true //Boolean on whether to preload all images before showing gallery
    setting.ispaused=!setting.autoplay[0] //ispaused reflects current state of gallery, autoplay[0] indicates whether gallery is set to auto play
    setting.currentstep=0 //keep track of # of slides slideshow has gone through
    setting.totalsteps=setting.imagearray.length*setting.autoplay[2] //Total steps limit: # of images x # of user specified cycles
    setting.fglayer=0, setting.bglayer=1 //index of active and background layer (switches after each change of slide)
    setting.oninit=setting.oninit || function(){}
    setting.onslide=setting.onslide || function(){}
    var preloadimages=[], longestdesc=null, loadedimages=0
    var dfd = (setting.preloadfirst)? jQuery.Deferred() : {resolve:function(){}, done:function(f){f()}} //create real deferred object unless preloadfirst setting is false or browser doesn't support it
    setting.longestdesc="" //get longest description of all slides. If no desciptions defined, variable contains ""
    setting.$loadinggif=(function(){ //preload and ref ajax loading gif
        var loadgif=new Image()
        loadgif.src=simpleGallery_navpanel.loadinggif
        return jQuery(loadgif).css({verticalAlign:'middle'}).wrap('<div style="position:absolute;text-align:center;width:100%;height:100%" />').parent()
    })()
    for (var i=0; i<setting.imagearray.length; i++){  //preload slideshow images

        preloadimages[i] = new Image()
        preloadimages[i].src=setting.imagearray[i][0]
        if (setting.imagearray[i][3] && setting.imagearray[i][3].length>setting.longestdesc.length)
            setting.longestdesc=setting.imagearray[i][3]
        jQuery(preloadimages[i]).bind('load error', function(){
            loadedimages++
            if (loadedimages==setting.imagearray.length){
                dfd.resolve() //indicate all images have been loaded
            }
        })
    }
    var slideshow=this
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var setting=slideshow.setting
        setting.$wrapperdiv=$('#'+setting.wrapperid).css({position:'relative', visibility:'visible', background:'white', overflow:'hidden', width:setting.dimensions[0], height:setting.dimensions[1]}).empty() //main gallery DIV
        if (setting.$wrapperdiv.length==0){ //if no wrapper DIV found
            alert("Error: DIV with ID \""+setting.wrapperid+"\" not found on page.")
            return
        }
        setting.$gallerylayers=$('<div class="gallerylayer"></div><div class="gallerylayer"></div>') //two stacked DIVs to display the actual slide 
            .css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:0})
            .appendTo(setting.$wrapperdiv)
        setting.$loadinggif.css({top:setting.dimensions[1]/2-30}).appendTo(setting.$wrapperdiv) //30 is assumed height of ajax loading gif
        setting.gallerylayers=setting.$gallerylayers.get() //cache stacked DIVs as DOM objects
        setting.navbuttons=simpleGallery.routines.addnavpanel(setting) //get 4 nav buttons DIVs as DOM objects
        if (setting.longestdesc!="") //if at least one slide contains a description (feature is enabled)
            setting.descdiv=simpleGallery.routines.adddescpanel(setting)
        $(setting.navbuttons).filter('img.navimages').css({opacity:0.8})
            .bind('mouseover mouseout', function(e){
                $(this).css({opacity:(e.type=="mouseover")? 1 : 0.8})
            })
            .bind('click', function(e){
                var keyword=e.target.title.toLowerCase()
                slideshow.navigate(keyword) //assign behavior to nav images
            })
        dfd.done(function () { //execute when all images have loaded

            setting.$loadinggif.remove()
            setting.$wrapperdiv.bind('mouseenter', function () {

                **setting.autoplay[0] = false;**
                debugger

            })
            setting.$wrapperdiv.bind('mouseleave', function () {

                setting.autoplay[0] = true;
                debugger



                ///////////////
            })

            slideshow.showslide(setting.curimage) //show initial slide
            setting.oninit.call(slideshow) //trigger oninit() event
            $(window).bind('unload', function () { //clean up and persist

                $(slideshow.setting.navbuttons).unbind()
                if (slideshow.setting.persist) //remember last shown image's index
                    simpleGallery.routines.setCookie("gallery-"+setting.wrapperid, setting.curimage)
                jQuery.each(slideshow.setting, function(k){
                    if (slideshow.setting[k] instanceof Array){
                        for (var i=0; i<slideshow.setting[k].length; i++){
                            if (slideshow.setting[k][i].tagName=="DIV") //catches 2 gallerylayer divs, gallerystatus div
                                slideshow.setting[k][i].innerHTML=null
                            slideshow.setting[k][i]=null
                        }
                    }
                    if (slideshow.setting[k].innerHTML) //catch gallerydesctext div
                        slideshow.setting[k].innerHTML=null
                    slideshow.setting[k]=null
                })
                slideshow=slideshow.setting=null
            })
        }) //end deferred code
    }) //end jQuery domload
}

simpleGallery.prototype={

    navigate:function(keyword){
        clearTimeout(this.setting.playtimer)
        this.setting.totalsteps=100000 //if any of the nav buttons are clicked on, set totalsteps limit to an "unreachable" number 
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(keyword))){
            this.showslide(parseInt(keyword))
        }
        else if (/(prev)|(next)/i.test(keyword)){
            this.showslide(keyword.toLowerCase())
        }
        else{ //if play|pause button
            var slideshow=this
            var $playbutton=$(this.setting.navbuttons).eq(1)
            if (!this.setting.ispaused){ //if pause Gallery
                this.setting.autoplay[0]=false
                $playbutton.attr({title:'Play', src:simpleGallery_navpanel.images[1]})
            }
            else if (this.setting.ispaused){ //if play Gallery
                this.setting.autoplay[0]=true
                this.setting.playtimer=setTimeout(function(){slideshow.showslide('next')}, this.setting.autoplay[1])
                $playbutton.attr({title:'Pause', src:simpleGallery_navpanel.images[3]})
            }
            slideshow.setting.ispaused=!slideshow.setting.ispaused
        }
    },

    showslide: function (keyword) {

        var slideshow=this
        var setting=slideshow.setting
        var totalimages=setting.imagearray.length
        var imgindex=(keyword=="next")? (setting.curimage<totalimages-1? setting.curimage+1 : 0)
            : (keyword=="prev")? (setting.curimage>0? setting.curimage-1 : totalimages-1)
            : Math.min(keyword, totalimages-1)
        setting.gallerylayers[setting.bglayer].innerHTML=simpleGallery.routines.getSlideHTML(setting.imagearray[imgindex])
        setting.$gallerylayers.eq(setting.bglayer).css({zIndex:1000, opacity:0}) //background layer becomes foreground
            .stop().css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:1}, setting.fadeduration, function(){ //Callback function after fade animation is complete:
                clearTimeout(setting.playtimer)
                setting.gallerylayers[setting.bglayer].innerHTML=null  //empty bglayer (previously fglayer before setting.fglayer=setting.bglayer was set below)
                try{
                    setting.onslide.call(slideshow, setting.gallerylayers[setting.fglayer], setting.curimage)
                }catch(e){
                    alert("Simple Controls Gallery: An error has occured somwhere in your code attached to the \"onslide\" event: "+e)
                }
                setting.currentstep+=1
                if (setting.autoplay[0]){
                    if (setting.currentstep<=setting.totalsteps)
                        setting.playtimer=setTimeout(function(){slideshow.showslide('next')}, setting.autoplay[1])
                    else
                        slideshow.navigate("play/pause")
                }
            }) //end callback function
        setting.gallerylayers[setting.fglayer].style.zIndex=999 //foreground layer becomes background
        setting.fglayer=setting.bglayer
        setting.bglayer=(setting.bglayer==0)? 1 : 0
        setting.curimage=imgindex
        setting.navbuttons[3].innerHTML=(setting.curimage+1) + '/' + setting.imagearray.length
        if (setting.imagearray[imgindex][3]){ //if this slide contains a description
            setting.$descpanel.css({visibility:'visible'})
            setting.descdiv.innerHTML=setting.imagearray[imgindex][3]
        }
        else if (setting.longestdesc!=""){ //if at least one slide contains a description (feature is enabled)
            setting.descdiv.innerHTML=null
            setting.$descpanel.css({visibility:'hidden'})

        }
    },

    showhidenavpanel:function(state){
        var setting=this.setting
        var endpoint=(state=="show")? setting.dimensions[1]-setting.panelheight : this.setting.dimensions[1]
        setting.$navpanel.stop().animate({top:endpoint}, simpleGallery_navpanel.slideduration)
        if (setting.longestdesc!="") //if at least one slide contains a description (feature is enabled)
            this.showhidedescpanel(state)
    },

    showhidedescpanel:function(state){
        var setting=this.setting
        var endpoint=(state=="show")? 0 : -setting.descpanelheight
        setting.$descpanel.stop().animate({top:endpoint}, simpleGallery_navpanel.slideduration)
    }
}

simpleGallery.routines={

    getSlideHTML:function(imgelement){
        var layerHTML=(imgelement[1])? '<a href="'+imgelement[1]+'" target="'+imgelement[2]+'">\n' : '' //hyperlink slide?
        layerHTML+='<img src="'+imgelement[0]+'" style="border-width:0" />'
        layerHTML+=(imgelement[1])? '</a>' : ''
        return layerHTML //return HTML for this layer
    },

    addnavpanel:function(setting){
        var interfaceHTML=''
        for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
            var imgstyle='position:relative; border:0; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; top:'+simpleGallery_navpanel.imageSpacing.offsetTop[i]+'px; margin-right:'+(i!=2? simpleGallery_navpanel.imageSpacing.spacing+'px' : 0)
            var title=(i==0? 'Prev' : (i==1)? (setting.ispaused? 'Play' : 'Pause') : 'Next')
            var imagesrc=(i==1)? simpleGallery_navpanel.images[(setting.ispaused)? 1 : 3] : simpleGallery_navpanel.images[i]
            interfaceHTML+='<img class="navimages" title="' + title + '" src="'+ imagesrc +'" style="'+imgstyle+'" /> '
        }
        interfaceHTML+='<div class="gallerystatus" style="margin-top:1px;Display:none;">' + (setting.curimage+1) + '/' + setting.imagearray.length + '</div>'
        setting.$navpanel=$('<div class="navpanellayer"></div>')
            .css({position:'absolute', width:'100%', height:setting.panelheight, left:0, top:setting.dimensions[1], font:simpleGallery_navpanel.panel.fontStyle, zIndex:'1001'})
            .appendTo(setting.$wrapperdiv)
        $('<div class="navpanelbg"  ></div><div class="navpanelfg" style="Display:none;"></div>') //create inner nav panel DIVs
            .css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:0, width:'100%', height:'100%'})
            .eq(0).css({ opacity:simpleGallery_navpanel.panel.opacity}).end() //"navpanelbg" div
            .eq(1).css({paddingTop:simpleGallery_navpanel.panel.paddingTop, textAlign:'center'}).html(interfaceHTML).end() //"navpanelfg" div
            .appendTo(setting.$navpanel)
        return setting.$navpanel.find('img.navimages, div.gallerystatus').get() //return 4 nav related images and DIVs as DOM objects
    },

    adddescpanel:function(setting){
        setting.$descpanel = $('<div class="gallerydesc" style="Display:none;><div class="gallerydescbg"></div><div class="gallerydescfg"><div class="gallerydesctext"></div></div></div>')
            .css({position:'absolute', width:'100%', left:0, top:-1000, zIndex:'1001'})
            .find('div').css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:0, width:'100%'})
            .eq(0).css({ opacity: simpleGallery_navpanel.panel.opacity }).end() //"gallerydescbg" div
            .eq(1).css({color:'white'}).end() //"gallerydescfg" div
            .eq(2).html(setting.longestdesc).end().end()
            .appendTo(setting.$wrapperdiv)
        var $gallerydesctext=setting.$descpanel.find('div.gallerydesctext')
        setting.descpanelheight=$gallerydesctext.outerHeight()
        setting.$descpanel.css({top:-setting.descpanelheight, height:setting.descpanelheight}).find('div').css({height:'100%'})
        return setting.$descpanel.find('div.gallerydesctext').get(0) //return gallery description DIV as a DOM object
    },

    getCookie:function(Name){ 
        var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i"); //construct RE to search for target name/value pair
        if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
            return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
        return null
    },

    setCookie:function(name, value){
        document.cookie = name+"=" + value + ";path=/"
    }
}
```

From above code only continuously rotation is working but mouseover and mouseleave is not working properly.

Comment: better to use css3 insted of jq for rotating image http://shankar-mydotnetsite.blogspot.in/search?q=image+rotation

Comment: I want slider image continouly with fade effect

Answer (score 0):

this the best for doing what you need

[Link](http://responsiveslides.com/)

just add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
```

Add Markup

```
<ul class="rslides">
   <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

and then script

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
   $(".rslides").responsiveSlides()({

    pause: false           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false

    });
  });
  </script>
```

[Exampel](http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.html)